# How can I get Shinylive python file paths to work?

Tags: python, pandas, py-shiny, py-shinylive

I am making a shiny application, but when I host it on shiny live using:

`python3 -m http.server --directory docs --bind localhost 8008` or hosting it on github.

The `filepaths` of the `csv` files I'm referring get the error `filenotfound`.

I tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.normpath("data_new.csv"))
df = pd.read_csv("data_new.csv"))
```

And other path manipulations but I always get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 44] No such file or directory:
```

Absolute paths don't work either.

Comment: Can you provide the project structure please? like does the script exist in the same directory a the .csv file? can you also use 'os' module to print the current working directory? and show us the results?